# Application Craft, Parse and PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build, applicationcraft

If I wanted to design apps that required data storage and were targeted for multiple mobile platform's, would using Application Craft to create the UI, Parse to store the data and PhoneGap to wrap it all up for the relevant target device be a potential way of approaching this?

What would be some of the limitations to this approach?

Some of the main things the app will do - 
I intend to have a mysql database, use PHP server side scripts to send JSON data to the app which then displays listings, allows users to add favourites, use geolocation features to get current location of user, accept PayPal and credit card payments and autogenerate and send emails from the app.

Answer (score 0):

@MurtazaM,

Your idea should work. You might want to consider some sort of indexed databased, and not an SQL database - as is typical for php. Mobile applications appear to work better with indexed DB (aka NOSQL database).

The reason is the initial lookup of the client is very fast, and you could build on that *or* tie it to a SQL database for the geolocation feature.

Jesse